# Progress bar slows the loop

Tags: julia

I've done some tests with the progress bar and it slows down the test code considerably.
Are there any alternatives or solutions? I'm looking for a way to track current index while looping and there are some primitive ways to put more conditions to print when step reached but isn't there something good that's built in?
Oh and one more question, Is there a way to print time elapsed from when the function started and display with the index? let me clarify, I know about @time and etc but is there a way to count time and display it with corresponding index like
`"Reached index $i in iteration in time $time"`
Code for the tests done:

```
function test(x)
   summ = BigInt(0);
   Juno.progress(name = "foo") do id
       for i = 1:x
           summ+=i;
           @info "foo" progress=i/x _id=id
       end
   end
   println("sum up to $x is $summ");
   return summ;
end
@benchmark test(10^4)

function test2(x)
   summ = BigInt(0);
   for i = 1:x
       summ+=i;
       (i%10 == 0) && println("Reached this milestone $i")
   end
   println("sum up to $x is $summ");
   return summ;
end
@benchmark test2(10^4)
```

EDIT 1

for Juno.progress:

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
memory estimate:  21.66 MiB
allocs estimate:  541269
--------------
minimum time:     336.595 ms (0.00% GC)
median time:      345.875 ms (0.00% GC)
mean time:        345.701 ms (0.64% GC)
maximum time:     356.436 ms (1.34% GC)
--------------
samples:          15
evals/sample:     1
```

For the crude simple version:

```
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 
memory estimate:  1.22 MiB
allocs estimate:  60046
--------------
minimum time:     111.251 ms (0.00% GC)
median time:      117.110 ms (0.00% GC)
mean time:        119.886 ms (0.51% GC)
maximum time:     168.116 ms (15.31% GC)
--------------
samples:          42
evals/sample:     1
```

Comment: Writing data to the screen is, fundamentally, slow.  The best solution is to (a) satisfy yourself that the code is operating correctly (test it, in other words) and then (b) trust it to do its work as rapidly as possible without obsessively watching its progress.

Comment: Also note that Juno's `@progress` macro (for `for` loops) is more sophisticated than your version in that it doesn't generate a log entry on *every* iteration (instead it only does that once your loop has progressed more than 0.5% -- this still has an overhead, but much smaller than what you're doing).

Comment: The thing is I want this tool to help me debug when runtime is long, I'm solving problems in project Euler and sometimes the computations are long if the algorithm is bad. But this implementation can give you an idea on the time it will take to compute. Sometimes even with a good algorithm it may take a while, it depends on the machine as well. But when dealing with the unknown it helps to see if it gets stuck after 10,50 or 80%.

Comment: I'm going to edit my code with @benchmark results so you'll see the disparity that I'm talking about. And self very, very crude implementation that is faster

Comment: On my machine `test` is ~430 times slower than the pure loop and the `Juno.@progress` version is ~7 times slower.

Comment: `test` is the one with Juno.Progress, Notice after my edit that even when I use `println("...")` every 10 iterations its still faster than Juno.progress

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd recommend using `Juno.@progress` directly for much better performance:

```
using BenchmarkTools

function test(x)
    summ = BigInt(0)
    Juno.progress(name = "foo") do id
        for i = 1:x
            summ += i
            @info "foo" progress = i / x _id = id
        end
    end
    println("sum up to $x is $summ")
    return summ
end
@benchmark test(10^4) # min: 326ms

function test1(x)
    summ = BigInt(0)
    Juno.@progress "foo" for i = 1:x
        summ += i
    end
    println("sum up to $x is $summ")
    return summ
end
@benchmark test1(10^4) # min 5.4ms

function test2(x)
    summ = BigInt(0)
    for i = 1:x
        summ += i
    end
    println("sum up to $x is $summ")
    return summ
end
@benchmark test2(10^4) # min 0.756ms


function test3(x)
   summ = BigInt(0);
   for i = 1:x
       summ+=i;
       (i%10 == 0) && println("Reached this milestone $i")
   end
   println("sum up to $x is $summ");
   return summ;
end
@benchmark test3(10^4) # min 33ms
```

`Juno.progress` can make no performance optimizations at all for you, but you can implement them manually:

```
function test4(x)
    summ = BigInt(0)
    update_interval = x÷200 # update every 0.5%
    Juno.progress(name = "foo") do id
        for i = 1:x
            summ += i
            if i % update_interval == 0
                @info "foo" progress = i / x _id = id
            end
        end
    end
    println("sum up to $x is $summ")
    return summ
end
@benchmark test4(10^4) # min: 5.2ms
```

Comment: While not important for original probem (I guess it has more complicated calculations), for such a simple loop you lose a lot of time in doing `%`, which is rather lengthy calculation. It is better to avoid it in tight loops if possible, for example by defining `cnt = 0` at the beginning of the function and changing condition to `if cnt == update_interval; cnt = 0; # progress ...; else cnt += 1` (SO not letting me righting code with proper identing in comment mode).

Answer (score 1):

As was stated by [High Performance Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44309/high-performance-mark) writing to the screen is fundamentally slow (crazy fast in human scale, very slow in computer scale.) You could abandon writing the output to the progress bar, but you can also simply update the progress bar less often. In your test case you're doing 10000 additions and updating the progress bar 10000 times. To be honest I've never used Julia and I have no idea what the progress bar looks like. Even if it is a GUI progress bar on a 4K screen and each of these updates actually changes it at all I guarantee a human can't see the difference. I would update it at the beginning (to be 0) and at the end (to be 100%) and then use an if statement with a modulo test to only update every so many additions. Example below in python which I'll claim is pseudo code since I've never used julia:

```
updateEvery = 2
for i in range(1,x):
    sum += i
    if x % updateEvery == 0:
        updateProgressBar(i/x)
```

By varying updateEvery you can decrease or increase the number of progress bar updates. You can even calculate it dynamically based on x, say updateEvery = x/100, this would mean the progress bar would line up pretty well to percentages. The inefficiency caused by the progress bar updates is also probably meaningless for small values of x and as x increases the number of updates per number to be added will decrease (because the total number of updates will be constant.

Oh and if you really need great performance to the counting clock tick level (which you probably don't,) [modulo is faster for powers of 2 as it can be done with a binary and operation](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/fast-modular-exponentiation). I assume Julia will figure this optimisation out for you and you can just use % and round the value of updateEvery to the next power of 2. Though if you really care about that level of performance you'd be best to just get rid of the progress bar to eliminate the loop altogether.

Comment: In Julia far as I read in the documentation the update is every 0.5% by default hence every `50` iterations in my example. I can try to lower the threshold as you suggested but it seems a bit pointless since my crude `println("...")` did better with output every 10 iterations. The question probably more directed to the inner workings of the @progress function. Not to mention that pure code runs in about `4ms` which is a about hundred times faster

Comment: This shouldn't make any difference to my approach as you'll be calling progress less often so whatever it is about @progress that is slowing you don't simply won't be happening as often.